# How do I annotate a C or C++ function using SAL to specify that it returns true/false if a parameter is non-NULL/NULL

Tags: c++, c, static-analysis, sal

When compiling with Microsoft's `/analyze` static analysis command line option for `cl.exe`, I get the warning

```
warning C6011: Dereferencing NULL pointer 'foo'
```

on a code path that calls a trivial function that guarantees that `foo` is not NULL where the analyzer thinks it can be.

The trivial function:

```c
bool check_ptr(void* ptr)
{
    if (!ptr)
    {
        // The original does more things here, but
        // the repro is valid even without that.
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The calling site:

```c
foo_t* foo = lookup_foo(id);
if (!check_ptr(foo))
    return;
foo->bar = 4711; // warning C6011: Dereferencing NULL pointer 'foo'
```

The analyzer is really bad at seeing through function calls, even trivial ones. If `check_ptr` is reduced to

```c
bool check_ptr(void* ptr)
{
    return !!ptr;
}
```

then the analyzer can deduce that `foo` cannot be NULL when dereferenced, but that's not an option. The checker function is there for a reason.

So, I assume that there is an ungodly SAL annotation combination that can be applied to `check_ptr` to convince the analyzer that if it returns `true`, then the `foo` argument is not NULL.

Is there such a SAL annotation?

**EDIT:** I found a SAL solution and added it as a separate answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74459650/6345

Comment: "So, I assume that there is an ungodly SAL annotation combination that can be applied" - or maybe the analyser is just poor and you are stuck with what you have.

Comment: Well, the analyzer is obviously poor (in this scenario), but there can still be such a SAL annotation lurking - I've seen examples that not even their mother would love... :)

Comment: Fact is that C++ is such a complicated language that it's not reasonable to expect *any* tool to get everything right.

Comment: Does the analyzer figure it out if you write the check_ptr function with a single return?  e.g. `bool check_ptr(void* ptr) { if (!ptr) { stuff(); } return !!ptr; }`

Comment: @JohannGerell perhaps you are looking for annotations such as `_Check_return_`, `_Success_`, `_On_failure_`, `_Pre_defensive_`, `_Post_defensive_`, and `_When_`?

Comment: I'm not sure the checker can deep inspect `check_ptr` unless it's trivial. If `check_ptr` were in a separate `.c`, it couldn't. A macro could solve this [with an extension?]: `#define check_ptr(ptr_) ({ int notnull_ = (ptr_ != NULL); if (! notnull_) check_ptr_isnull(ptr_); notnull_; })`

Comment: @CraigEstey I believe that is the point of this kind of annotation, checker doesn't inspect deep into code, it only check both call-side and impl-side follow the specified rule. (I'm not sure how sal works tbh)

Comment: @BenVoigt I found that the single-return behavior varied depending on what `stuff()` was comprised of... Anyway, I found a SAL solution and added it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to SAL annotate the `check_ptr` function so that the analyzer knows what it does, by using `_Post_equal_to_`. By annotating the function return declaration with `_Post_equal_to_(!!p)`, the analyzer knows that the return value is non-zero if `p` is non-NULL.

Added a complete minimal repro example on [godbolt / Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/5sj9j7dY3) that looks more like the actual usage scenario in my code. Note the `UNCOMMENT NEXT LINE TO REMOVE` comment.

```c
// Compile with these cl.exe command line options: /TC /WX -std:c17 /analyze
// https://godbolt.org/z/5sj9j7dY3
#include <sal.h>

typedef struct source_location {
    const char* file;
    int line;
} source_location;

// UNCOMMENT NEXT LINE TO REMOVE "warning C6011: Dereferencing NULL pointer"
//_Post_equal_to_(!!p)
int check_ptr__(void* p, source_location location);

#define check_ptr(p) \
    check_ptr__((p), (source_location) { __FILE__, __LINE__ }) 

// '_In_opt_' tells the analyzer that 'i' can validly be NULL
void minimal_analyzer_repro(_In_opt_ int* i)
{
    if (check_ptr(i))
        *i = 4711; // "warning C6011: Dereferencing NULL pointer"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly using SAL, but a generic answer that should work all the time: instead of returning bool, you might take two lambdas: one for then, one for else:

```
template<typename Then, typename Else>
void if_check_ptr(Foo* ptr, Then then, Else els)
{
    if (!ptr)
    {
        // The original does more things here, but
        // the repro is valid even without that.
        then(*ptr);
    } else {
        els();
    }
}

// usage:
if_check_ptr(
    lookup_foo(id),
    /*then*/ [&](Foo& foo) { foo.bar = 4711; },
    /*else*/ []() {}
);
```

You could even have `lookup_foo()` and `if_check_ptr()` in one call.

Comment: Gotta work in C proper too (which is why I  added the C tag :) )

Comment: @JohannGerell In c, you're less lucky. Function ptrs would make it slow and clumsy. You can try to write a macro, but meh :)

Comment: Note that the lambda conversion has also lost the effect of `return` from the call site.

Comment: @BenVoigt This is a demonstrative example. There are two ways to go from this. 1: full cps, i.e., `return if_check_ptr(ptr, then, els, next)`, where `next` is the lambda that is the rest of the funciton. 2: Allowing `if_check_ptr` to return a value; then returning whether to return. And yes, I feel your pain: in fact, I once started to write a c++ proposal for parametric statement expressions.

Comment: And if the call site is in a loop, add a y-combinator to make the continuation able to invoke itself?   Aaaaaggggh my C++ is getting contaminated with functional programming!!!!

Comment: It's definitely a nice trick to make life easier for the static analyzer, but I also understand why Johann doesn't want to go down that rabbit hole.

Comment: @lorro your `if` is missing an `else`, so the `els()` callback is *always* called regardless of whether `ptr` is null or not.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Fixed, thanks for spotting!

Comment: I found a SAL solution, so I added it as a separate answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74459650/6345